# Meteor user property undefined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Users `waitOn` a data subscription:

```
waitOn: function(){
    if(Meteor.user()){
        var current_user_admin_status = Meteor.user().admin;
        console.log(current_user_admin_status);
        return Meteor.subscribe('users', current_user_admin_status);
    }
}
```

But `current_user_admin_status` always returns `null`, even though I can go into the db and find the `admin` field

`db.users.find({"_id" : "6Mqx5Ky92bZfhaX8A"}, {"admin" : 1})`

> { "_id" : "6Mqx5Ky92bZfhaX8A", "admin" : true }

Im defining this variable on the client, to pass to the server to only publish user collection if current user is an admin, but it keeps getting caught on the `null` `if else` statement

```
Meteor.publish('users', function(current_user_admin_status){
    if(!this.userId){
        console.log('you are not signed in');
    }
    else if( current_user_admin_status = 'null' ){
        console.log('you are not an admin');

    } else if ( current_user_admin_status = 'false' ) {
        console.log('you are not an admin');

    } else if (current_user_admin_status = 'undefined'){
        console.log('you are not an admi');

    } else {
        console.log('you are logged in as an admin');
        return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {createdAt: 1, admin: 1, emails: 1, username: 1, first_name: 1, last_name: 1}}); 
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not 100% but I'm guessing other fields don't get put into the user function/object. Try moving your admin field into the profile prop - `Meteor.user().profile.isAdmin`, that's how I get to mine.

Comment: my user collection does not have a profile field by default

Comment: Looking at the doc for `Meteor.user()`: "By default the server publishes username, emails, and profile (writable by user). See Meteor.users for more on the fields used in user documents." From the little research I just did, you're gonna have to edit the account-ui package to change the object, otherwise you'll have to query separately for the additional fields.

Comment: where did you write to the profile field?

Comment: I set the field at registration as default false. If you update the profile field, it is auto-published to the currentUser. Anything inside it is editable by that user. As long as you're not using a schema then you can just update your account to add `profile.admin`

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of important points to note here. First, relating to the question comments, it is **not** safe to add an admin field to `user.profile` unless you have added specific `allow/deny` rules to prevent it from being edited. See the first point in [this article](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes). By default the `user.profile` field is editable by its user and in general you should store sensitive fields such as admin outside it.

Second, the most likely reason you are not receiving `user.profile.admin` on the client is because you are not publishing it. You should first create a publication for the logged in user to send fields outside of the default fields noted in the comments down to the user.

Lastly, there is an excellent and widely used package for handling authorization, `roles`, that has already addressed the security concerns above. I recommend using that: https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I would have made a terrible mistake. I do explicitly deny all updates, but I wasn't aware that it was editable without - close call. I have moved my roles to a separate collection and now filter by id.